# ArcPy MP won't save any changes

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, tkinter

I am trying to write a script that sets up a basic Pro project to make sketches for work, but for some reason no matter what I do when I run the script no changes to the projects themselves are happening. I can see where some changes are happening when I rerun later like when I had a print statement for my text elements I could see clones being made but none showed on the map.

If I run the first script inside my template I can at least see the temp layers being made

```
import arcpy.lr
import tkinter
import arcpy
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import os

arnold =  r"C:\Users\DB43952\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.8\ArcCatalog\Connection to sqldw.sde\ARNOLD.DBO.ARNOLD"
table = r"C:\Users\DB43952\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.8\ArcCatalog\Connection to SQL2.sde\Program_Management.dbo.ProgramsContracts_Mapping"
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("700x300")
frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(window, text="Sketch Creator", padx=20,pady=10)
frame.pack(pady=10, padx=10, side = "left")
var = tkinter.IntVar(frame)
t = tkinter.StringVar(frame)

def main():
    path = (r"\\san1\GIS\ProgramsContracts\Sketches\\" + t.get())
    if (os.path.exists(path)):
        messagebox.showerror("WARNING", "This job already has a folder present!!!")
    else:
        window.destroy()
        os.mkdir(path)
        arcpy.env.workspace = (r"\\san1\GIS\ProgramsContracts\Sketches\\" + t.get())
        projecttemp = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\Users\DB43952\Desktop\ArcProTemplates\Template\Teml.aprx")
        print (var.get())
        if (var.get() == 2):
            print ("HI")
            l = arcpy.MakeRouteEventLayer_lr(arnold,"AH_RoadID",table, "AH_RoadID LINE AH_BLM AH_ELM","Line")
            lL = l.getOutput(0)
            llL = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(lL,"Lines")
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(llL,"llL")
            ##arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("llL","NEW_SELECTION","Job_No = '" + t.get() + "'","INVERT")
            ###arcpy.Delete_management("llL")
            desc = arcpy.Describe(llL)
            mapa = projecttemp.listMaps()[0]
            print (desc.catalogPath)
            Lyt = projecttemp.listLayouts()[0]
            Jobnum = Lyt.listElements("TEXT_ELEMENT")
            for i in Jobnum:
                if (i.name == "Jobnum"):
                    print (i.name, i.text)
                    i.text = "Job" + t.get()
            projecttemp.saveACopy(r"\\san1\GIS\ProgramsContracts\Sketches\\" + t.get() + r"\\" + t.get())
            #Jobnum.text = t.get()


def go(var):
    a = var.get()
    main()

tkinter.Label(frame,text = "Job Number").pack(anchor = "w")
textbox = tkinter.Entry(frame, textvariable = t).pack()

tkinter.Label(frame,text = "Data Type").pack(anchor = "w")
point = tkinter.Radiobutton(frame, text = "Point",variable = var, value = 1).pack(anchor = "w")
line = tkinter.Radiobutton(frame, text = "Line", variable = var, value = 2).pack(anchor = "w")

ttk.Button(frame, text = "Sumbit", command = lambda: go(var)).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Second code also trying

```
import arcpy 
a = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = a.listMaps()[0]
l = m.listLayers()
for i in l:
    if (i.name == "shields_arnold"):
        lbl = i.listLabelClasses()[0]
        lbl.expression = "AH_Route"
        lbl.visible = True
        i.showLabels = True
a.saveACopy(r"C:\Users\DB43952\Desktop\ArcProTemplates\TempV2\hi.aprx")
```